# jqTouch - why does the transition has no animation?

Tags: jqtouch

I'm using jqTouch. Trying to figure out why when the scene / div change, it just change abruptly without the slide animation?

Here is the setting that I have now:
   var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
    slideSelector: '.link',
    useAnimations: true
   });

Again the scene change works just fine, just that I don't see the slide animation.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

Found out why.
The slideSelector needs to be applied to <a> tag.

Tee